# C++ Makefile g++ and the "std=" Flag seem not to work

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I'm trying to figure out makefiles and already have a little project directory I want to test it on. Sadly I can't seem to satisfy the compiler's needs. g++ warns me I need the `-std=c++11` flag which I have and further prints errors to C++11 related features (like threads).
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here are the first lines of error:

```
make
g++    -c -o Graphics.o Graphics.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:35:0,
                 from Graphics.h:4,
                 from Graphics.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
  ^
In file included from Graphics.cpp:1:0:
```

And here the Makefile:

```make
csrc=$(wildcard *.c)
cppsrc=$(wildcard *.cpp)
obj=$(cppsrc:.cpp=.o) $(csrc:.c=.o)

CXXC = g++
#CXXCFLAGS = -std=c++14
EXEC = myprog

LOPENGL = -lGLEW -lGLM
LSFML = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
LDFLAGS = $(LSFML) $(LOPENGL)

all: $(obj)
    $(CXXC) -std=c++11 $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXEC)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm .f $(obj)
```

I cannot figure it out. Internet is just saying "Well, add the Flag then" when I search the error. 
I already tried:

- switching the flag's position or writing it directly in the line (you can actually see this by the commented `CXXCFLAGS`).
- using different flags `-std=c++11`, `-std=gnu++11`, `-std=c++14`

I also noticed the flag not showing up when the compiler runs (to see in the second line of the errors).

Also if you can point out anything wrong with format, other errors or conventional things please be sure to leave a comment to that I'm eager to improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You commented out the relevant line:

```
#CXXCFLAGS = -std=c++14
```

Remove the comment to make it work. Furthermore, the variables are misspelled. Their actual names are `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` (no trailing/intermittent `C`!).

You might also need to specify that you are dealing with C++ files:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

To explain what’s wrong: the following rule

```
all: $(obj)
    $(CXXC) -std=c++11 $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXEC)
```

isn’t compiling the code. Instead, it’s linking the — already compiled — object files (which is what `$(obj)` refers to). But to obtain these object files, the source files need to be compiled and `make` is using an [implicit rule for `.o` files](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html#SEC95) for this.

— There are more errors in your Makefile. For instance, the `clean` rule should invoke `rm -f` instead of `rm .f`. You need to be a *a lot* more meticulous when writing code.

Comment: Normally, the `clean` rule is written with `$(RM)` to use the built-in default (your point is valid, though).

Comment: A good practice for the link command is to copy Make's built-in rule (which can be seen using `make --print-data-base`.  That command is `$(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@`

Comment: Ok i commented out the line because it was not working and added the flag below (I actually explained this). The . was a typing error. Is the CXXFLAGS line added implicitly to CXX ? I did not type CXXFLAGS after i commented it. EDIT : The link to the implicit rules are priceless thank you !

Comment: I think i got it now fully : The .o are created implicitly with the given flags if i name the variables correctly CXX CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS after that I can use the .o to make my -o $(EXEC) which i have to write myself. So what was wrong was the name of the variable. I swear if you don't know about implicity here you're confused as hell. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[Konrad's answer](/a/41045273) explains why your `g++` command isn't being executed with your desired argument.

You can use `make --print-data-base` to help you understand what rules are built-in to Make.  The ones relevant here are

- ```make
  %.o: %.cpp
  #  recipe to execute (built-in):
      $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
  ```

  This is the rule that makes your object files from your `*.cpp` source files.  Following the definition of `COMPILE.cpp`, we find it comes back to

  ```make
  COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
  ```

  So we just need to add our option into `CXXFLAGS` (not `CPPFLAGS` - that's for C preprocessor, and is shared with the C language):

  ```make
  CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
  ```
- ```make
  %: %.cc
  #  recipe to execute (built-in):
      $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
  ```

  This is the link step that we want to copy as the command to produce the executable from the object files.

A couple of other things to note:

- Your `all` target never creates a file called `all`, so the link step will happen even if the executable is up to date.
- You forget to enable `-Wall` for the diagnostics you always want.
- Your `clean` target has misspelt `-f`, and doesn't clean object files that no longer have corresponding source files (i.e. when you remove a source).
- I normally make `clean` remove editor backup files, too.

---

Here's my improved version of your makefile:

```make
EXEC = myprog

csrc := $(wildcard *.c)
cppsrc := $(wildcard *.cpp)
obj := $(cppsrc:.cpp=.o) $(csrc:.c=.o)

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra

LDLIBS += -lGLEW -lGLM
LDLIBS += -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(objs)
        $(LINK.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation ! I'm of course reading several tutorials at this point but its difficult to sort out what is really necessary and what is style/opinion. You showed a lot of features the others didn't even mention.